# Bluetooth Server and Client in android

Tags: android, server, bluetooth, client

I'm trying to create a `bluetooth` `server` and `client` in android.

The bluetooth server in android can view all the connected devices and create a data of connected devices and saved it in the sqlite db in android. The server and client must also be connected.

Where can I get some reference for this one? Is this one possible? How do I achieve this? I don't know where to start.

Are there any ways to do this? Any links where i can start or will help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this links. Hope it will provide what you need :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices

https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html